# Prettier code formatter does not work like what I want

Tags: prettier, formatter

Prettier getting hard to read my code, it refixed like that:

```js
 let justBlackKingOverThere = pieceNameInTheBoard.map(
    (item) => item.slice(0, 11) == "blackKnight"
  );
```

but I want that:

```js
let justBlackKingOverThere = pieceNameInTheBoard.map((item) => item.slice(0, 11) == "blackKnight")
```

Is there a solution or different code formatter that you recommend?

I try also different formatter but some of them are same.

Comment: Prettier is an _opinionated_ formatter, with very few [options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html). If you don't agree with it, find another (but recommendations are off-topic here).

Answer (score 0):

You can config Prettier to avoid breaking lines within arrow function parameter by setting 'arrowParens' to "avoid".

```
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid"
}
```